# Configuring WordPress .htaccess to view subfolders

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress installation with an `.htaccess` file that looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I tried installing a fresh copy of WordPress into a subdirectory for a separate blog and am getting 404 errors within the root WordPress when I try to view it. I'm assuming this is because of the `.htaccess` file.

How do I change it so that I can view the subfolder?

Answer (score 35):

For future reference, you may want to try this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Worked for me having a wordpress installation in the root aswell as another in a subdirectory. Simply used your code in the subdirectories htaccess. THANKS!

Comment: This rule: RewriteRule ewriteRule . /blog2/index.php [L] makes PHP $_SESSION issues - I can't unset selected $_SESSION vars.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit#2**: ok i think i figured this out, but it's pretty messy.

modify your base wordpress install's .htaccess file to look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog2/.*
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

now, load a new copy of wordpress into "blog2/", and copy your `wp-config.php` file over to it. edit the "/blog2/wp-config.php" file and change the `$table_prefix` to something different than your first blog. (this will install both wordpresses into the same database).

once you've done that, you should be able to go to:

```
http://yourdomain.com/blog2/
```

and finish up the installation without issue. the initial problem was that the new copy of wordpress kept trying to use the first copy's `wp-config.php` file. moving it over manually fixed that all up.

because i'm insane, i tested this with two fresh copies, wrote a few test articles, and was able to navigate around without issue, so it should work :)