# disable wordpress from subdirectory?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Is it possible to disable wordpress from a sub-directory?
Wordpress is currently installed in `root`.

So using wordpress' own CMS-functionality by going to `Settings->General` and changing `Site-adress-URL` wouldn't accomplish that since it would just move wordpress into a subdirectory. (which pretty much is the opposite of what i want to accomplish).

Is there any way to make wordpress ignore a specific subdirectory. Eg. `Uploads/` to make me create standalone code there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring WordPress .htaccess to view subfolders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196500/configuring-wordpress-htaccess-to-view-subfolders)

Answer (score 1):

By default this should just work. The .htaccess file has a rule to ignore existing folders and files from rewrites. Creating a folder next to wordPress with custom code should work.