# page redirect issue in sub folder

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, hyperlink, root

i have installed wordpress in a sub-folder but whenever i click on a page link in sub-folder then it redirects to a page that is in root folder.
the root folder also have a wordpress site.

**what i want**
to stop redirect to root folder and access the page in sub-folder.

**Note**
whenever i hover on the menu(page) link it show the real page URL but when i click then it redirects me to root folder that has a same page.

i know that there is some issue in the .htaccess file but unable to find exact solution as i have searched [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) [this](https://wpscholar.com/blog/simple-redirects-with-htaccess/) and [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-creating-redirects-in-wordpress/) and a lot more  but found nothing. i am totaly stuck with this issue.

Comment: Have you updated the site URL on your dashboard?

Comment: You should probably check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196500/configuring-wordpress-htaccess-to-view-subfolders

Comment: First you have a original wordpress site from your root folder? If Yes it will cause some conflicts,

Did you change your url link using admin settings>general?

or you can refer to this https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: both home and site url needs to be correct in the DB, wp_options

Comment: @andychukse ..yes i have already updated those..

Comment: there is no issue in DB, WP_OPTION .. i have set them all

Comment: @ Machavity please check those answers that does't solve my problem at all.. in the 2nd answer he edit the file to merge both database but i don't want to do that