# Browser ignores the url path on the first load

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a Wordpress site that is migrated to a new server. Along with the migration, it now also has a subfolder /en which is a different version of the website targeted for international audience. The problem I am facing is that if I try to load the site example.com/en, on the first load it redirects to example.com. But if I load example.com/en on the second try it goes to the subfolder website. And it is browser specific. I have this problem on Chrome and Safari but not on Firefox

I have already tried clearing the cache in the CMS level and also on the browser, this hasn't helped in any way. Could it be because of DNS switching from older server to the new server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas on how to find the root of the problem:

1. Check the site from a different network / device to make sure it's not the DNS cache
2. Check the .htaccess file of the server, maybe theres a misconfiguration
3. Use a site like [this one](https://redirectdetective.com/) to trace the redirect

If nothing helpes you could just wait a few hours, maybe the DNS servers take some time to update all the settings.

Comment: 1. I have checked it from a different network. The site performance is incosistent.
2. only added this solution to .htaccess in the subfolder

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196500/configuring-wordpress-htaccess-to-view-subfolders

3. The redirect is happening for /en to /en/ . Just adding a trailing slash at the end. Not sure if this will cause any issue because it's not redirecting to .com
The DNS switch was done 2 days ago.