# I move all the files and folder from the wordpress root directory to wordpress sub directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to duplicate to Wordpress files through the Wordpress file manager . But suddenly I just move all the files and folder from the Wordpress root directory to the sub directory name as haris now if I open this http://www.emcaviation.com/EMC/haris/wp-login.php and use the right logins. It again redirect to  this http://www.emcaviation.com/EMC/wp-login.php and it doesn't exist. Please let me now what should I do now ?

Comment: Read this guide: https://deliciousbrains.com/move-wordpress-root-subdirectory/

Comment: i can be able to login because as i put right logins it redirects again to this link  http://www.emcaviation.com/EMC/wp-login.php

Comment: Please update your htaccess. [htaccess rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196500/configuring-wordpress-htaccess-to-view-subfolders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code to `functions.php` in active theme. When you open login page `yourdomain.com/EMC/haris/wp-login.php` (you don't have to log in) the options will be updated. After all remove the code from the `functions.php`.

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://yourdomain.com/EMC/haris' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://yourdomain.com/EMC/haris' );
```

Comment: how can i edit functions.php . I cant be able to login even with the right logins details.

Comment: Do you have access to files via FTP or to database via phpMyAdmin?

Comment: i dont have it . my client just give me the wordpres logins only .

Comment: I can not help you. All the ways that come to my mind require either access to the database or the ability to edit a `wp-config.php` or `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Aoa... Move all WP folders in to that SUB Directory including `wp-content` `wp-includes` and files that belong to Wodpress.

Comment: i cant be able to login through wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

If your production site is installed in a subdirectory, but your development site is installed in the public root, then a change you make on your development site might break when it’s migrated to the production site.

You need to access the server as it needs code-level and server-level changes. You've different solutions to fix this like:
1.

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://emcaviation.com/EMC/haris' );
update_option( 'home', 'https://emcaviation.com/EMC/haris' );
```

Use the above code in your functions.php(of the active theme).

2. 2nd way You can use your URL with "?123" like example.com/?123.
3. You need to access .htaccess file and create a rule for this(redirect rule).